# Господа, помогите с задачей

Tags: binary

Оператор настроил терминал, чтобы он циклически передавал команды для выполнения определенной программы, но из-за атаки словарь закодированных команд был потерян. Необходимо срочно вернуть дрон на базу.

Нам известно, какие команды дрон выполняет и какую зашифрованную последовательность передает терминал. Нужно установить команду кратчайшей длины для возвращения на базу и передать ее дрону.

Всего возможно 6 команд: Вперед, Назад, Вправо, Влево, Сигнал, Вернуться.

Каждая из команд зашифрована двоичным кодом, не длиннее 5 бит. 
Весь набор команд удовлетворяет условию Фано, когда никакой код команды не является началом другого кода команды.

ЗАШИФРОВАННАЯ ПОСЛЕДОВАТЕЛЬНОСТЬ: 
10110111010111001000011100001000111

Команды: Вперед Вперед Сигнал Влево Вперед Сигнал Влево Влево Назад Сигнал Назад Вправо Сигнал

Comment: Чем конкретно помочь-то? На каком этапе решения застряли?

Comment: Я запутался и выбился из сил, чтобы продолжить это делать, пожалуйста, помогите

Comment: Как мы можем помочь, если вы не сознаётесь, с чем в этой задаче надо помочь?

Comment: Со всем, я не понимаю как.

Comment: Не бьётся. Должно быть `10 10 111 0 10 111 0 0 10000 111 10000 1000 111` - одна единица пропущена. Соответственно возврат - 2 вправо и 2 назад в любом порядке, 18 бит.

Comment: 10000 и 1000 не может быть при наличии 10. Допустимые 110x(y). У меня тоже не разбилась последовательность

Comment: Извините, последовательность: 10110111010111001000011100001000111

Answer (score -1, accepted):

С исправленной последовательностью всё получается, код возврата 1001.

Разбиваем, следя за повторами:

```
101 101 11 0 101 11 0 0 10000 11 10000 10001 11
```

Команда не может начинаться с нуля, с 11, со 101 - уже использовано. 1, 10 не может быть, т.к. являются префиксами. 1000 является префиксом, остаётся 1001. (10010 и 10011 подходят, но длиннее)

Comment: Боже, каким же дебилом нужно быть, чтобы молча минусовать прошлогодний ответ...